# Mongo cursor object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looping through a cursorObject and getting my document properties in an unexpected order.

For example, it's reading a set of observations with property name u1, u2, u3,etc.. in the order u2, u3, u1,... This wouldn't normally matter but I'm putting it straight into an array for some data manipulations.

```
def cursorToList(cursorObject):
    data_list = []

    for observation in cursorObject:
        data_list.append([str(observation['Tags']), str(observation['Id']), int(observation['u1']), int(observation['u2']), int(observation['u3']), int(observation['u4']), int(observation['u5'])])

    return data_list
```

Mongo isn't necessarily the best DB for my data as it's shaped as a table but I wanted to use it.

Is there some quirk which causes this to happen? Can supply code sample if needed

Comment: Please supply a code demonstrating the problem. Thanks.

Comment: is `cursorObject` just a dictionary, because dictionary keys aren't ordered

Comment: I added my example. @depperm yes it's a dictionary! Any way to order the dictionary keys? Should I perform a sort on my array :/

Comment: Wait no, cursorObject is whatever cursor object comes from pymongo. But it's used like a dictionary